# Completing a MAX() but using data from a few more tables

Tags: mysql, sql, max

well I eventually got to a max() on one table pulling correctly using max() - took me sometime to understand what was going on and reading the limits of mysql when using it

I have spent a some time doing some demo data on sqlfiddle (one below is with just the max on the one table

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fff224/1

what i would like (and to absorb as ive tried for the last 2 hours on getting this to work) is how to incorporate another tables that dont need to use max (i have included these in the sqlfiddle

the result i would be after would be

```
case_number full_address    case owner  client  compiled date(max())    recommendation
1000      1 high street       bob     london        14/12/2012                   let
1001      2 high street       ken     Compton       13/12/2013                   sell
1002      3 high street      ken      Leeds        14/12/2013                    sell
```

completing the inner joins between from client\staff\ to case process im fine with its just this nested select max im falling over on

Comment: @Strawberry That looks probably to be a typo for `('1000','2012-12-14','let'),`

Comment: yes sorry it was a typo i have corrected the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.case_number
     , p.full_address
     , s.case_owner_name 'case owner'
     , c.client_name client
     , r.compiled_date
     , r.recommendation
  FROM case_process p
  JOIN staff s
    ON s.case_owner_number = p.case_owner_number
  JOIN client c
    ON c.client_number = p.client_number
  JOIN reporting r
    ON r.case_number = p.case_number
  JOIN (SELECT case_number,MAX(compiled_date) max_compiled_date FROM reporting GROUP BY case_number) x
    ON x.case_number = r.case_number
   AND x.max_compiled_date = r.compiled_date;

 +-------------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
 | case_number | full_address  | case owner | client  | compiled_date | recommendation |
 +-------------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
 |        1000 | 1 high street | Bob        | London  | 2012-12-14    | let            |
 |        1001 | 2 high street | Ken        | Compton | 2013-12-13    | sell           |
 |        1002 | 3 high street | Ken        | Leeds   | 2012-12-14    | sell           |
 +-------------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
 3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

 fiddle of same... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fff224/7
```